# IBM Worklight 7.1- Unable to use locally saved file in android device using window.open getting exception as ''android.os.FileUriExposedException:"

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MFP 7.1 : Getting error "android.os.FileUriExposedException:" when Locally saved PDF document is opening using window.open().

```
"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.trib.devicebee.oqic/files/healthcard_13.pdf";*
window.open(outputPath, "_system", "location=yes,hidden=no,closebuttoncaption=Close");
```

have added below to  AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <provider android:authorities="com.sample.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"> 
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/> 
        </provider>
```

created provide_paths.xml :

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

Comment: If you were to do this in a plain Cordova application ( no MFP) , does it work?

Comment: No I did not tried, actually I am not good at creating only cordova applications.